# To save list in CSV file python?

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I want to transpose row into column and then save words in CSV file. The problem is only last value of column after transpose is save in file, and if i append string with list, it save in file but characters not words.
Anyone help me to sort it. Thanks in advance

```
import re
import csv

app =[]
with open('afterstem.csv') as f:
     words = [x.split() for x in f]

for x in zip(*words):
   for y in x:
      res=y
      newstr  = re.sub('"', r'', res)
      app = app + list(res)
      #print("AFTER" ,newstr)

with open(r"removequotes.csv", "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n', delimiter='\t')
    for val in app:
        writer.writerow(val) 
    output.close()
```

The output save in file look like this:

[image]

But i want "Bank" in one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
for column in zip(*words):
   newrows = [[word.replace('"', '')] for word in column]
   app.extend(newrows)
```

to put all columns one after another into the first column.

`newrow = [[word.replace('"', '')] for word in column]` creates a new list for each column with double quotes stripped and wrapped into a list and `app.extend(newrow)` appends all of these lists to your result variable `app`.

You got your result because of your inner loop and in particular its last line:

```
for y in x:
   ...
   app = app + list(res)
```

The for-loop takes each word in each column and `list(res)` converts the string with the word into a list of characters. So `"Bank"` becomes `['B', 'a', 'n', 'k']`, etc. Then `app = app + list(res)` creates a new list that contains every item from `app` and the characters from the word and assigns that to `app`.

In the end you got a array containing every letter from the file instead of a array with all words in the file in the right order. The call to `writer.writerow(val)` then wrote each letter as it's own row.

BTW: If your input also uses tabs to delimit columns, it might be easier to use `list(csv.reader(f, lineterminator='\n', delimiter='\t'))` instead of your simple read with `split()` and stripping of quotes.

Comment: cg909 It save the output but not in row, it save in multiple column.

Comment: so you don't want to transpose (rows -> columns, columns -> rows) but get all columns into one column? Is that correct?

Comment: I transposed row into column , now the problem is data save in csv file but after one cell other cell is empty. e.g my file output is:          http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=30914943673593648277

Comment: open the above link and you found 'token.csv' file, is my output file

Comment: I corrected my solution. For your second problem an input file along with your output file would be helpful